# member access for react component lifecycle methods in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I use the typescript react starter for tsx driven react implementations, it is mandatory to specify member access (public, private, protected) for any method that I use in context of a class component. This comes from ( i believe ) the tslint.json file.

What should be the reasoning behind what access specifiers the lifecycle methods should have.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

React lifecycle methods should all be public since they are going to be called externally (by React).